# Create a space between scraped elements using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I've looked for an answer but can't seem to find one. Apologies if I've missed one.

I'm using rvest to scrape some web pages. I want to gather all the content from each page that is assigned a particular class (.description). There can be multiple elements within this class (e.g. a number of paragraphs, lists, breaks etc.). I'm fine getting the content but if there's no space between the closing tag of one element and the opening tag of the next in the page's html (which isn't at all unexpected) then there's no space between the words from each in the resulting text extract.

Is there a way I can force a space between each separate element from the description class? I tried identifying each unique element, scraping them individually then pasting them together using collapse = " " but not every element is on every page (e.g. some don't have lists) which caused me a few problems.

```
website <- read_html("https://www.websiteaddress.com")
snippet <- html_nodes(website, ".description")
snippet <- html_text(snippet)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT** @anpami suggested linking to the site. It's not actually a live site, just practicing on some pages I scripted whilst I learn how to get to grips with rvest. The following is a simplified version of the page structure but should be illustrative. With html written like this, the scraped paragraphs from the .description div ends up like this: "A paragraph elementAnother paragraph elementA third paragraph element". The list items do the same. I'm hoping to force a space between the text where one paragraph tag ends and the next starts.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <style>
    body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    color: white;
    }
    
    .description {
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgb(225,225,225);
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    color: black;
    }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div class="description">
   <h2>Title of description section</h2>
    <p>A paragraph element</p><p>Another paragraph element</p><p>A third paragraph element</p>
    <ul>
     <li>A list item</li><li>Second list item</li><li>Third list item</li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div>
   <h2>Title of section I'm not interested in</h2>
    <p>A paragraph from a section I'm not interested in</p><p>Another paragraph from a section I'm not interested in</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you provide us with a specific URL to a website that exhibits such a structure, it would be helpful (so as to replicate your code and try out some possible solutions)!

Comment: @anpami - thanks. It's not from a live site, just some pages I've scripted to practice with. I've added an illustrative example.